# Print and save output to excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I'm newbie learning python, I have the code which prints output to python console, Now i want to print the output to console as well save it on excel file also

```
  def print_results(results):



print()
  print('Profile Name: %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName'))
  print()

  # Print header.
  output = []
  for header in results.get('columnHeaders'):
    output.append('%30s' % header.get('name'))
  print(''.join(output))

  # Print data table.
  if results.get('rows', []):
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      output = []
      for cell in row:
        output.append('%30s' % cell)
      print(''.join(output))

  else:
    print('No Rows Found')
```

Comment: Try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have pandas ,you can save your output in a pandas **DataFrame** and then save it to an excel file using

```
DataFrame.to_excel("Output_File.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

the module xlwt can do it
f = xlwt.Workbook() 
f.save('demo1.xlsx')